# How to detect long press on Google maps markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

I guess Google maps does not have a long press / taphold event handler. Is the below code a way to implement this?

Comment: is **what** a way to implement this?

Comment: Hi ALexander, I want to detect long press event on google maps markers .

Comment: Please edit your question (see the edit link directly under the tags) and add the code which you have tried. Also explain what you expect the code to do and why you are stuck now. The way your question is written right now, you're not too likely to receive any answers.

Comment: Looks a lot better now, but you probably wouldn't post a question here if it worked as you expected, right? Could you elaborate on what your problem is with the above code?

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich: I have edited the question and marked the answer. Thanks for guiding me!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have implemeted the long press feature using mouse up and mouse down event listener. Thanks!!

```
var longpress = false;
        
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', function (event) {
    (longpress) ? console.log("Long Press") : console.log("Short Press");
});
        
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', function(event){
    start = new Date().getTime();           
});
        
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseup', function(event){
    end = new Date().getTime();
    longpress = (end - start < 500) ? false : true;         
});
```

Comment: For me this worked perfectly (after adding listeners to also reset start on dragstart and dragend events) whereas the solution by rafamds proved a bit flakey.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old post, but I came across the same problem and I found what I think to be a better solution than the one that @Anbarasan Thangapalam suggested.

**Solution:**

```
var mousedUp = false;
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', function(event){ 
    mousedUp = false;
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(mousedUp === false){
            //do something if the mouse was still down
            //after 500ms        
        }
    }, 500);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseup', function(event){ 
    mousedUp = true;
});
```

I think this approach might be better to understand, with less lines of code and less listener functions.

To avoid firing the timeout function on a drag event, just duplicate the **`mouseup`** function and change it with **`dragstart`**. Like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(event){ 
    mousedUp = true;
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks for taking time to post your solution!

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the solution by Rafaelmorais (with the drag listener), but I think the first declaration of the trigger flag "mousedUp" should be true.  I changed that trigger variable (also renamed it to be a little more intuitive) and it works.

A few notes FYI...

After the long press event is let go, a click event would also fire (if you have a click listener set).  To prevent double events, you can use a (!longPressed) inside the click listener to suppress the click event running (if you want).

I cleared the timeout to prevent strange instances where the function checked back to see if longPressActive was still true and it had been unset/reset and still triggered the event.

Mousedown event fires with ANY mouse button (not relevant for touch events).

Dragend is not required because dragstart clears the timeout

```
var longPressTimeout = null;
var longPressActive = false;
var longPressed = false;

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', function(event){
    longPressActive = true;
    longPressed = false;
    longPressTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        if(longPressActive === true){
            console.log("Long Press")
            longPressed = true;
            //do something after marker long pressed for 1000ms
        }
    }, 1000);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseup', function(event){
    clearTimeout(longPressTimeout); 
    longPressActive = false;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(event){
    clearTimeout(longPressTimeout); 
    longPressActive = false;
});
```

(I'm posting this as a solution because I don't have enough rep to comment yet)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the below method worked. To see if it is a `rightclick` or `longPress` just check if the event type is "contextmenu" inside your handler.

```
gMaps.event.addListener(overlay, 'click', function() {
    if(event.type === "contextmenu"){
     //longpress handler codes
    }
}
```